# Typo3 9.5 : Add a new field to a new page type

Tags: typo3

I make a new page type with the help of this doc : https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/9.5/en-us/ApiOverview/PageTypes/

I want now to customize it by adding a new field to my page

For example a field under "title" field

[image]

I checked the doc and didn't find how to do this

Some one can explain me how to custom my new page please?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/HowTo/ExtendingTca/Examples/Index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

extending `pages` records is the same than extending `tt_content`records.

there is a an example to this in the documentation: [extend tt_content and use data processing](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/11.5/en-us/ApiOverview/ContentElements/AddingYourOwnContentElements.html#extended-example-extend-tt-content-and-use-data-processing).
This link is to the documentation of TYPO3 11 as this version is state of the art and gets support. For older versions the declarations may vary a little, but the concept is the same:

- add new fields in database and TCA.
- create a variant (`type`) and declare which fields should be shown for this variant.
- you may need additional `getter` and `setter` or controller for this variant